# How do I echo out to variables?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to post the `firstname` and `lastname` of the user. What I did was:

```html
<td><?php echo $row_message['firstname']['lastname']; ?></td>
```

And I'm getting `Warning: Illegal string offset`

Could someone teach me how to do this? I've read stuff about it but I can't seem to understand it.

Here's my DB Schema:

[DB Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cP4ls.png)

Comment: `echo $row_message['firstname']; echo $row_message['lastname'];`

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Thank you so much, you can post it as your answer. How do I put space in the middle tho?

Comment: 1) `echo $row_message['firstname'] . " " . $row_message['lastname'];` 2) `echo $row_message['firstname']; echo " "; echo $row_message['lastname'];`

Comment: echo $row_message['firstname']." ".$row_message['lastname'];

Comment: You can also use `var_dump($row_message);` and `print_r($row_message);` to print the all contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should retrieve them separately, like this

```
<td><?php echo $row_message['firstname'].' '.$row_message['lastname']; ?></td>
```